# Conditional split in SSIS DATEADD method error

Tags: ssis

I am in the process of uploading the delta load to a CSV file. I have set up a conditional split in the package which will compare the last modified date with the below expression:

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2)
```

I need to replace above with:

```
(DT_STR,2,1252)DATEADD("dd",-1,GETDATE())
```

But it is throwing a warning error message. The package is failing.

Comment: And the warning error message is? Also, what are you attempting to do with the above expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible thing you can replace with that second expression is your `GETDATE()` method. More precisely, you are probably trying to retrieve the previous day based on your second expression.

**From:**

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2)
```

**Replaced:**

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",DATEADD("dd",-1,GETDATE())),2)
```

**Example:**

[image: GetDate() example]

Comment: Thanks Milen it worked like a sweet!!!! May i know what difference it makes while using DateAdd first..

Comment: You are making calculations on the date itself with DATEADD. (DATEADD http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141719.aspx). You supply a date, a date is returned (DT_DBTIMESTAMP). DATEPART returns an integer (DT_I4). (DATEPART http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586.aspx) Because of this, other way around will not work.